# Windows Universal 8.1 Facebook Login for Phone: OnActivated, then what?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm attempting to use the Facebook SDK and Facebook Client for Windows 7.0.5 to add login to my Windows Phone 8.1 (RT not silverlight) app, but documentation is sparse...

if I'm understanding everything correctly, I can use the command:

```
Session.ActiveSession.LoginWithBehavior("email,public_profile,user_friends", FacebookLoginBehavior.LoginBehaviorAppwithMobileInternetFallback);
```

which is going to launch the app or browser, either way suspending my app, then relaunching it on completion.

I then have a handler in the app.xaml.cs to handle the relaunch of the app from the login result:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnActivated(args);

    // You can setup a event handler to be called back when the authentication has finished
    Session.OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished += OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished;

    var protocolArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
    LifecycleHelper.FacebookAuthenticationReceived(protocolArgs);
}

private async void OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished(AccessTokenData session)
{
    // here the authentication succeeded callback will be received.
    // put your login logic here
    await Client.LoginUserFacebook(session.FacebookId, session.AccessToken);
}
```

where "Client.LoginUserFacebook" is my custom local client that will take the id and token to authenticate them into my system.

However, what do I do next? My app is going to launch again and take them to the login screen isn't it? how am I supposed to go from the OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished to the logged in view if all of this is happening completely outside the UI thread?

Comment: My problem is that my OnActivated method never fires haha. I don't get it why not. Does yours?

Comment: yes it does you have to add the protocol activation in the declarations tab, despite the instructions saying to use msft-{packageid} I actually had to use fb{appid} where appid is your facebook application id. my app isn't in the store yet so i dont know if it will change but it appears that fb returns this protocol not the windows one.

Comment: I did this but it does not fire. My app isn't in the store either. I am using the Facebook Client SDK as you. What am I doing wrong? Sry for asking a question to your question page xD

Comment: Update: I just change my invoke from LoginBehaviorApplicationOnly to LoginBehaviorMobileInternetExplorerOnly and now the event fires. That's really strange. Why it does not when returning from the Facebook app? Well, I'll use the mobile browser then. Thank you for your help!

Comment: actually you're right I forgot that I had to do the same thing. perhaps it has something to do with the emulator? glad you got it working, but how are you handling the return and logging in the user?

Comment: After I got it working I can understand your question. I would like to know it as well :) For now my app just opens again and I am at the login page but I don't know how to change the page to tell the user that he's logged in. Maybe we could make an event handler for this?

Comment: the way I'm doing it is simply calling the navigation service, which I'm guessing is what you're supposed to do, but it doesn't feel right, as I don't want to see the intro screen. I guess what I can do in the handler is navigate to a "logging in" screen and then after that redirect to the logged in page. can't think of any better way to do it...

Comment: @XHotSniperX How did you get your OnActivated method to fire? I am also using LoginBehaviorMobileInternetExplorerOnly to try logging in. It goes to Internet Explorer, I login to Facebook and it returns back to my app to the page that I configured in the FacebookConfig.xml file but the OnActivated method does not fire

Comment: did you register a protocol activation in the app manifest? on my app i had to add the protocol fb{0} where {0} is the app id. i haven't published yet so i dont know if this will change but hopefully, not and hopefully you find this helpful!